# Print without magenta toner (cartridge)?

Tags: printer

I have my magenta toner (cartridge) in Epson AccuLaser C1100 depleted. Now printer does not print. If toner (cartridge) is inside, printer says toner (cartridge) is low and not working. If I take toner (cartridge) out, then printer says insert toner (cartridge).

*P.S.*

I mean I want to print black and white. Since printer turns to error mode prior to any communication with computer, I think this looks impossible.

Comment: Have you tried to print only in black and white? (Not greyscale)

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. Computer says nothing, printer is an error state. If I try to enter printer menu, I fail. It says "unable to clear error" when I am pressing big button.

Comment: @malakrsnaslava why "not grayscale"? I had at my workplace one Epson color ink printer and it was doing the same thing - we always had to buy replacement inks just to print from black ink only, if they were depleted. I see Epson hasn't changed their ways...

Comment: I do not have Epson, but on some others we could print in black & white. Some printers, Canon Pixma IP5300's manual states; "Printing in grayscale may use colour inks". So I thought maybe it could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** replace the toner cartridge.

From the printer reference guide (ftp://download.epson-europe.com/pub/download/205/epson20540eu.pdf, accessible from this [link](http://esupport.epson-europe.com/FileDetails.aspx?lng=en-US&data=tgU002FqCAQg2JDh7ZlozEek9qHbvtmCoiLC&id=20540)):

[image]

Not the behavior I would expect, looks like Epson chose a revenue-friendly feature here.